# Python: Return a list

Tags: python, function, return

I've looked at a few of the answers for a function and the return and I'm not sure I get it. I get the return ends a function. Mine is only returning one line when there are several in the txt file.

```
def readList(champs):
    for i in range(len(champs)):
        champ = champs[i]
        return(str(i+93) + " - " + champ)
```

Under my main()

```
        if command == "see":
            readChamps = readList(champs)
            print(readChamps)
```

Intended outcome:

93 - Manchester United

94 - Manchester United

95 - Blackburn Rovers

Current outcome:

93 - Manchester United

I understand using print for def readList(champs):, but I want to understand calling the return. I could not get yield to work neither.

Comment: Do you understand how to *create* a list? Do you understand how to put values into a list? You need to have a list with the correct values in it to return, before you can return it.

Comment: I have my list created in:
```
FILENAME = "champs.txt"

def writeToTextFile(champs):
    with open(FILENAME, "a") as file:
        for champ in champs:
            file.write(champ + "\n")
```
It currently holds the list that is in the intended outcome on the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `return` inside your loop, which causes the function to exit in the first iteration of the loop.

If you just want to print the lines, you can do the following:

```
def readList(champs):
    for i, champ in enumerate(champs):
        print(str(i+93) + " - " + champ)
```

and in your `main`:

```
if command == "see":
    readList(champs)
```

If you want to return values from `readList`, you should do it after you finish your loop:

```
def readList(champs):
    output = []
    for i, champ in enumerate(champs):
        output.append(str(i+93) + " - " + champ)
    return output

# and in your main:
readChamps = readList(champs) 
print(readChamps)

# readChamps is a list of strings. If you want to print it line by line, try:
for i in readChamps:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Rrint instead of return definitely works as I want it to. However, I still want to sort out how to return instead. Thank you.

Comment: @Genoxidus I've updated my solution. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: These changes perfected my desired outcome.
if command == "see":
            readChamps = readListFromTextFile(champs)
            #print(readChamps)
            for i in readChamps:
                print(i)

Answer (score 2):

As you write yourself, `return` ends the function hence the loop executes exactly once.

You can use a list comprehension and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def readList(champs):
    return ['{} - {}'.format(i, champ) for i, champ in enumerate(champs, 93)]
```

Alternatively, create a list, `.append` to it and return it in the end:

```
def readList(champs):
    output = []
    for i, champ in enumerate(champs, 93):
        output.append('{} - {}'.format(i, champ))
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
def readlist(champs):
    champs = [str(i+93) + "-" + champs[i] for i in range(len(champs))]
    return champs
```

Comment: Thank you. This make my champ undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "return" a value without terminating the function, you can use `yield` instead of `return`. This makes the result an iterator of values instead of a single value.

```
def readList(champs):
    for i in range(len(champs)):
        champ = champs[i]
        yield (str(i+93) + " - " + champ)
```

Then to print it out, you can unpack the iterator with a *. Maybe like

```
print(*readList(champs), sep='\n')
```

Or you can use a for loop like

```
for line in readList(champs):
    print(line)
```

This will print one line at a time, instead of all at once, which may be what you want if the number of lines is large.

---

This approach using `yield` may be superior than printing directly inside of the `readList()` function, because it avoids side effects, which means that you can do more than just print it. You could also save the result to a file, for example.

This approach may also be better than saving it to a list and returning the whole list if the number of items is large, because it can process one at a time and doesn't have to store them all in memory at once.

---

And I would have written the function more like this

```
def read_list(champs):
    for i, champ in enumerate(champs, 93)):
        yield f'{i} - {champ}'
```

Standard PEP 8 style uses `snake_case` for function names. If you use `enumerate()` instead of `range()`, you don't have to look up the `champ` yourself each loop with the index. And you can start counting at 93, so you no longer have to add it. F-strings will automatically convert what they are interpolating, so you don't have to call `str()` yourself.